# Why does Eclipse treat java.lang.Exception specially

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing some code cleaning, removing catch Throwable and catch Exception, but I noticed some odd behavior in Eclipse.

In this piece of code, Eclipse will mark the IOException path as unreachable, which is correct, but not the Exception path. Isn't the Exception path equally unreachable? 
java.lang.Exception is a checked Exception? Right?

```
    try {
        log.info("Some message");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Comment: Say `log` was `null`, what would happen in this code?

Comment: log.info can still raise an exception. log could be null, or the info method could throw an Exception back to this code. And it's not Eclipse that's telling you that. it's the Java compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.Exception` is the parent class of all the Exceptions (although not all the `Throwable`s!). As it is also the parent of [`java.lang.RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), you can always attempt to catch it, as any piece of code may throw a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Thanks, I was sure that Exception was the root of only the checked exceptions. Silly me :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception` catch block is not unreachable, because `Exception` also includes all **unchecked** exceptions (exceptions which extend `RuntimeException`, which is a subclass of `Exception`).

The difference between checked and unchecked exceptions is that for the former, a method is required to either catch and handle the exception, or declare that it might throw the exception with a `throws` clause; for the latter (unchecked) this requirement doesn't exist, a method can throw an unchecked exception even if it doesn't declare that it might throw it. (See [The Catch or Specify Requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials for more details).

To determine if a `catch` block is unreachable, the compiler only looks at the **checked** exceptions that might happen in the code in the `try` block.

Since your `catch (Exception e)` also includes catching **unchecked** exceptions, it's always allowed to have this block.